# How to use OpenApi annotations in spring-webflux RouterFunction endpoints?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, openapi

I am currently working on a project where I use spring functional web programming. I usually use annotations of swagger 2 in restController but with functional web programming I can not find where ! The place to tell the app to do a search for endpoints (like basepackage in Docket) and load swagger in an html page.
Here is my code:

```
@Configuration
public class RouterClient{

@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes(ClientHandler client){
  return route(GET("/api/client"), client::findAll)
      .andRoute(POST("/api/client"),client::add);
  }
}
```

Config Class:

```
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfiguration{

  @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi groupOpenApi() {
        String paths[] = {"/api/**"};
        String packagesToscan[] = {"com.demo.client"};
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().setGroup("groups").pathsToMatch(paths).packagesToScan(packagesToscan)
                .build();
    }

}
```

The dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.32</version>
    </dependency>
```

The result :

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Functional endpoints are supported since 1.3.8 (early May). See releases on [GitHub](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/releases).

**Have a look at this**: https://springdoc.org/#spring-webfluxwebmvc-fn-with-functional-endpoints

The easiest way to see your endpoints on the Swagger UI is to add the `@RouterOperation` annotation to your `RouterFunction` methods (containing a single route), and specify the `beanClass` and `beanMethod` used in it. However, in your case, there are multiple routes on a single method, so you must also use the `@RouterOperations` annotation. These cases are well documented in the link above.

It seems like the current implementation of springdoc-openapi only allows to manually add the documentation.

Comment: updated direct link to the section: https://springdoc.org/#spring-webfluxwebmvc-fn-with-functional-endpoints

Comment: If I simply put a `@RouterOperation` annotation, request bodies are not registered by Swagger UI. I mean it makes sense: it can't statically know I call `request.bodyToMono(UserDto.class)` in the method. Am I expected to annotate my handler methods with `@Operation`?

Comment: It seems I *am*, judging from Spring's documentation. I never explicitly specified any `@Operation`s when I had `@RestController`s. Why do I have to do that in this brave new reactive world?

Answer (score 0):

https://springdoc.org/
You need springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui and @RouterOperation.

Answer (score 0):

set

```
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false
```

This will skip classpath scanning (`springfox`) for the API annotations. (OAS3 replaced these in v3) and replace them with reading in the spec file (`json`/`yaml`).

Put the documentation in the Spec files, as one can generate any number of clients from these. Easiest way to start with legacy code is to copy the `/api-docs/` files generated by `springfox`.

You can go to `editor.swagger.io`, load in the version 2 yaml and convert it to version 3 if `springfox` still doesn't do that. Then work with `yaml` files. (it's a contract UP-Front specification for a reason)

Answer (score -3):

spring-webflux with Functional Endpoints, will be available in the future release